# Reduce space between columns in res.cls latex resume

Tags: class, latex, pdflatex

How do I reduce the space between two columns in the res.cls?

I have the following code in my latex document right now

This is the main Latex file.

```
  %---
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%---

\documentclass[margin, 10pt]{res} % Use the res.cls style, the font size can be changed to 11pt or 12pt here
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{helvet} % Default font is the helvetica postscript font

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\sectionwidth}{1.8in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.2in} % Text width of the document

\newcommand{\ts}{\textsuperscript}

\begin{document}

%----
%   NAME AND ADDRESS SECTION
%-----

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{{\LARGE {{Google}}}} % Name at the top
 \moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\href{https://google.com}{https://google.com}}

%------

\begin{resume}

%----
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----
\section{{\sc{Education}}}

{\textbf{Institute Name} }  \hfill Jul. 2018 - Jul. 2018 \\
Undergraduate \hfill USA

\begin{itemize} [leftmargin=0.5cm]
    \item GPA of 4.0 / 4.0
\end{itemize}
```

I am using the res.cls file for styling, in the same directory as the above file. Find the res.cls I am using here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JhjCG846CW_21DP3XQdv2u4o_0LLh88i/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
\setlength{\sectionwidth}{1.8in}
```

Add the following combination of length changes after that:

```
\addtolength{\sectionwidth}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
```

Any adjustment in `\oddsidemargin` will push the section title further into the left margin, hence the dual adjustment so it remains in the current position. Change the lengths to suit your needs.

Comment: That would increase the margin on the left side. How do I increase the width of the right side content without affecting the margins?

Comment: @R.Pal: That decreases left side margin, bringing the section title to the text block. Perhaps you can be more clear about what you want by virtue of a drawing that includes pointers on what you want specifically. Can you do that?

Comment: Making the sectionwidth 0.8 will increase the left side margin and decrease the gap between two columns.

However, I want the margins to be fixed (small) and also decrease the space between the two columns.

Comment: @R.Pal: See the updated answer.